# How to create array of LocalDate in jetbrains Exposed table

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, kotlin-exposed

I have a Postgres Table that has a column of "date[]" representing various dates that a user has a specific behavior, meaning each cell can have multiple dates (for example {"2022-10-31", "2022-10-10"}).

This is connected to an API built in Ktor using Exposed library. I'm trying to represent this in Ktor.

The object property is

```
val user_behaviour_dates: List<LocalDate?>?
```

where LocalDate comes from kotlinx.datetime library, so that it can be serialized.

How can I represent this in the Users Table? I have successfully represented another list property that is:

```
val equipment: List<String?>?
```

using [this](https://github.com/LorittaBot/Loritta/blob/db577852a76266d207361b7d8257d24b4ee0b947/platforms/discord/legacy/src/main/java/com/mrpowergamerbr/loritta/utils/exposed/array.kt) library that supports array for ColumnType as

```
var equipment = array<String?>("equipment", VarCharColumnType(120)).nullable()
```

but when I am trying to do this with LocalDate, i get the error that the IDateColumnType (from Exposed library) doesn't have constructors (since its an interface).

Here is the Table. Any ideas?

```
object UsersTable: Table() {

val userId : Column<Int> = integer("id").autoIncrement()
override val primaryKey: PrimaryKey = PrimaryKey(userId)
val email = varchar("email", 128).uniqueIndex()
val password = varchar("password", 64)
val username = varchar("username", 120)

var equipment = array<String?>("equipment", VarCharColumnType(120)).nullable()

var user_behaviour_dates = array<LocalDate?>("user_behaviour_dates ", IDateColumnType()).nullable()
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve. If you want have all data in a single field using `array` column than you have to ask library author to support it.

Otherwise I would suggest to create a separate table `UsersBehaviorDatesTable` and use native Exposed references to manage it. You can check [that part](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DAO#many-to-one-reference) of wiki

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I finally solved it using SQL Date type, and Kotlin LocalDate. I will consider the second part of your answer later in the project. Would you say having a separate table and using references would be more performant?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it like this:

```
    val user_behaviour_dates = array<Date?>("user_behaviour_dates ", KotlinLocalDateColumnType()).nullable()
```

The "Date?" type from (java.sql.Date) is recognized by Postgres table, and instead of using IDateColumnType Exposed interface, I used KotlinLocalDateColumnType() which also can be serialized/deserialized in the form of LocalDate as a field.

Then when writing a function in the API of updating a User for example, a conversion is needed from Kotlin LocalDate to SQL Date (with an in-between javaLocalDate) so that it can be put in the table.

```
override suspend fun updateUserPrefs(
 email: String,
 equipment: List<String?>?,
 userBehaviour: List<LocalDate?>?
) {

 return run {

     // Kotlin LocalDate to SQL Date conversion

     var userBehaviourDatesSqlDate: MutableList<Date?>? = null

     if (userBehaviour != null) {
         for (i in userBehaviour.indices) {
             val localDate = userBehaviour[i]
             val date: Date = Date.valueOf(localDate!!.toJavaLocalDate())
             if (userBehaviourDatesSqlDate == null) userBehaviourDatesSqlDate = mutableListOf()
             userBehaviourDatesSqlDate.add(date)
         }
     }

     // Database update

     DatabaseFactory.dbQuery {
         UsersTable.update({ UsersTable.email eq email }) { user ->

             user[UsersTable.equipment] = equipment?.toTypedArray()
             user[UsersTable.user_behaviour_dates ] = userBehaviourDatesSqlDate?.toTypedArray()

         }
     }

 }
}
```